# Need code of URL rewriting in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I know there are many questions and answers regarding URL rewriting but i have not found any which can solve my equation so i am putting here a question regarding my problem after a long and deep search.

I need this URL:

```
www.example.com/team/suman/1
```

to be changed to:

```
www.example.com/team/suman
```

I am not finding any way to write code in htaccess.

Comment: Is it the exact source url, or are there more?

Comment: you appear to have rewritten urls already.

Comment: (1)what is `team`, what is `suman`, and what is `1` in your URL? (2)why do you want to remove the suffix `/1` from URL? some more info is needed to help answer your question.

Comment: @Cole it's zend not him I suppose (I mean, he didn't do it on his own ;)

Comment: I am using ZEND..and yes @cole it is already rewritten as I am using Socialengine CMS which is based on ZEND framework...

Comment: @ariefbayu In the URL : team is team and suman is team's title and 1 is team's id...

Comment: ZEND is a framework included in all PHP releases (just FYI; so you don't need to mention it)

Comment: @Cole thank you for the info but is there any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I assume "to be changed" means redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^team/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([0-9]+)$  team/$1 [L]
```

Not tested.. but you can try :)

Comment: What error you are getting? try to put full URL instead of short. try to explain a little bit what you want to achieve?

Comment: You need to be specific. your question is still not clear. Is Mod Rewrite working on our server? see the above two lines, did you add that before your rule?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to be specific:
`RewriteRule ^team/suman/(.*)$ /team/suman [L,R]`

L with R flag if you want to change url in address bar if not just use only L flag

Comment: i want globally change here suman may be change with other name.... your code is for specific  but i want globally

Comment: maybe: `RewriteRule ^team/(.*)/([0-9]+)$ /team/$1 [L,R]` but you must be more specific when asking question i just give you rule but i dont know the most important thing why you want this